# Structure Tensor for pixel in matlab

Tags: computer-vision

I am given a project of Saliency Detection in images. I want to calculate structure tensor for each pixel and then get eigen values from it. How I can do this? I am totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to calculate the the spatial derivative Ix and Iy. You do this by taking the finite difference between each pixel and it's nieghbhoor. Look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_derivatives

Second for each pixel you.calculate in a neighborhood around the pixel the following sums
Ix^2 Iy^2 and IxIy and put them in a 2x2 matrix in the closing way

Ix^2 IxIy

IxIy Iy^2

This matrix is the structure matrix

Third calculate the eign values of this matrix.

For an explanation about the matrix look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_tensor